# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) Ajax Rails error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am currently just trying to add some ajax to my rails application. I am getting this error when I try to create a new post. I know the post is created because when I refresh the page the post ends up in the list of posts.

#### posts_controller.rb

```
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
```

#### app/views/posts/index.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@post, remote: true) do |f| %>
      <div class="modal fade" id="mynewpost" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Suggested Invite</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="mynewpost">Close</button>
              <%= submit_tag "Create", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
            </div>
          </div>
```

#### app/views/posts/create.js.erb

```
alert("Post Created!!");
```

#### routes.rb

```
resources :posts
```

Now I expect that after clicking submit I should see poste created!But I don't. I just get an internal server error. From here I have no idea what to do. Please let me know if there is any additional information I can provide.

Comment: when you see that error, you need to look in the rails console for the cause. adding that output to the question would make it easier to help

Comment: @maxple unfortunately I am running the server in a docker container and am not getting any logs. So I am debugging using the console in Chrome

Comment: It's unfortunate you don't have access to the logs! Can't you get inside the container? `docker exec .... /bin/bash` then you check the logs. Better yet, you could define your rails app's log directory as a docker volume so that you have access to it from your development box. It seems like you need to fix your development environment first so that you can see what's going on when you test your code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it could be a syntax error

```
{ render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
```

It would be simpler to render the json from the post and control the logic in javascript.

```
render json: @post
```

and then in javascript have a listener on the form's success

```
    $("form").on("ajax:complete", (xhr, status) ->
           alert("Post was created!");
    )
    $("form").("ajax:error", (xhr, data, status) ->
      "Handle errors here";
    )
```

Comment: Where would this JS logic be put into?

Comment: For simplicity, you can just place it in application.js

Comment: I actually scaffolded to create these controller actions, so I don't think there is a syntax error. For some reason my format.js is not getting hit. I know this because the data is being saved and everything but breaks at format.js